# How can I do my table to not exceed my card width with CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm doing the responsive of my table that is inside a card, but in small sizes, the table go-outs of the card due to the width of the table exceed the card one I tried several times to solve this, like putting flex to the parent and trying to put the table width equal to the card but didn't work the card should always stay centred and inside of the card

This is a picture of the error: https://www.screencast.com/t/25bnSngK

This is a picture of how should look: https://www.screencast.com/t/dK683SPzO

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Our css -->
    <title>ABOUT</title>
    <style>

        /*----------------Styles for the fonts----------------*/
        .museo-sans-900{
            font-family: museo-sans, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 900;
       }
       .museo-sans-700{
            font-family: museo-sans, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700; 
       }
       .museo-sans-500{
            font-family: museo-sans, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 500; 
       }
       /*------------------------------------------------------*/
       /*----------------------Colours-------------------------*/
       .Riverbed-orange{
            color: #FF6900;
       }
       .Riverbed-black{
           color: #3D3D3D ;
       }
       /*------------------------------------------------------*/
        body  {
            background-image: url("images/about_page_bgd.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            align-items: center;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
        
        .title{
            color: #3D3D3D;
            margin-top: 34px;
        }
       .orange-container{
            position: relative;    
            text-align: center ;
       }
       
       .orange-container .sub-title{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 999;
            margin: 0 auto;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
            color: white;
        }
        .introduction{
            margin-left: 115px;
            margin-right: 125px; 
        }

        hr{
            border: 1px solid #AB989D;
            width: 100%;
        }
       td {
            text-align: center !important; 
            width: 25% ;
        }
        .outlined-btn {
            border: 4.77px solid var(--unnamed-color-ff6900);
            border: 5px solid #FF6900;
            border-radius: 24px;
            max-width: fit-content;
            background: white;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .outlined-btn:hover{
            color: #FF6900;
            width: 100%;
        }
        div > .outlined-btn {
            width: 100% ;
            position: relative;
        }
       
        /* ============== Media Queries ================== */

        /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
        @media (max-width: 576px) { 
            
        }

        /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
        @media (max-width: 768px) {
          
            .sub-title{
                font-size: 1em !important;
            }
            .title{
                font-size: 1.17em !important;
            }
         
        }

        /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
        @media (max-width: 992px) {
            .introduction{
                margin-left: 10%;
                margin-right: 10%; 
            }
            img{
                width: 80%;
            }
        }

        /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
        @media (max-width: 1200px) {
            .sub-title{
                font-size: 1.17em;
            }
            .title{
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-10">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1 class="title mx-auto museo-sans-900"><span class="d-flex justify-content-center">ABOUT THE RIVERBED</span>GLOBAL USER CONFERENCE</h1>
                    <div class="orange-container">
                        <img src="images/about_page_ribbon.svg" width="75%">
                        <h2 class="mx-auto sub-title museo-sans-700 my-auto">LEARN. CONNECT. EXPLORE.</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="museo-sans-500 introduction">
                        <p>Today, organizations are hyper focused on 1) accelerating digital transformation, 2) enabling work-from-anywhere models, and 3) strengthening operational resilience. The success or failure of these strategic priorities depends largely on digital technologies and the performance of IT infrastructure that must deliver and secure these technologies.</p>
                        <p>As technology professionals and IT practitioners, now is the time for you to lead your organization through change.</p>
                       
                        
                            <table class="table table-borderless ">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" class=" border-right border-left border-top border-bottom text-center text-white" style="background: #FFB022;">8:30 – 9:00</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class=" border-right border-left border-top border-bottom text-center text-white" style="background: #FF6900;;">9:00 – 11:00</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="border-right border-left border-top border-bottom text-center text-white" style="background: #FFB022;">11:00 – 5:00</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="border-right border-left border-bottom Riverbed-black"><strong>Open Networking<br><br> Hall <br><br> Info Desk <br><br> Chat<br><br></strong></td>
                                    <td class="border-right border-left border-bottom Riverbed-black"><strong> Welcome<br><br>  Keynotes <br><br>Roadmap<br><br></td></strong>
                                    <td class="border-right border-left border-bottom Riverbed-black"><strong>35+ Performance and Visibility Technical Sessions<br><br> Sessions featuring Microsoft, Gigamon, Netskope <br><br> Customer Stories and Use Cases<br><br> </strong></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
<!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your lengthy words trying to fit in a smaller space. Try adding this in your css file

```
.table-borderless td {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

**Hint:** Consider reducing the padding to about `padding: 0.25rem;` in your `td`  for smaller devices. Maybe down sizing the font a bit also would help.

Answer (score 0):

You put a col-sm-8 on the parent div that contains the card. This means that for small screens this div cannot be any wider than 2/3 of the width of it's parent). It seems that this does not give enough width to contain the table.

You can make the table smaller by turning word-break on as shown in Becky's answer, but I found that making the containing div slightly wider by changing the col-sm-8 into col-sm-9 or col-sm-10 gives a more pretty result.